# JQuery custom attribute attr() or prop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the initial part of my js code, I create  element as below:

```
$('<input/>', {
               type: 'text',
               class: 'edit country',
               handle: '123456',
               name: 'customer'
               })
```

Then I add it to dom.

Sometime later, I want to retrieve the info stored in this element:

```
$(input_element).prop('handle') #which return 'undefined'
$(input_element).attr('handle') #which give me '123456'

$(input_element).prop('name') #which return 'customer'
$(input_element).attr('name') #which give me 'customer'
```

I want to know what is wrong with my prop() method for fetching 'handle'? Is that because 'handle' is not standard HTML attribute?

I have read this post [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)
No big help.

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: This post will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html

Comment: Attributes are not properties. Most of the standard HTML attributes are mapped to properties, but custom attributes aren't. Also keep in mind that custom attributes should be prefixed by `data-` for your document to be valid.

Comment: ↑↑↑ Like said, you should use: `"data-handle": '123456',` and then you could use: `$(input_element).data('handle')`

Comment: @JayBlanchard, thanks, that link helps

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, thanks for explanation, I have a better understanding on properties and attributes now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)